# Map are not showing before click on submit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function calculateRoute(from, to) {
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 10,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.08672, 79.42444),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var mapObject = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            var directionsRequest = {
                origin: from,
                destination: to,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
            };
            directionsService.route(
                directionsRequest,
                function(response, status)
                {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
                    {
                        new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                            map: mapObject,
                            directions: response
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    $("#error").append("Unable to retrieve your route<br />");
                }
            );
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if (typeof navigator.geolocation == "undefined") {
                $("#error").text("Your browser doesn't support the Geolocation API");
                return;
            }
            $("#from-link, #to-link").click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var addressId = this.id.substring(0, this.id.indexOf("-"));
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                    geocoder.geocode({
                        "location": new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
                    },
                    function(results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                        $("#" + addressId).val(results[0].formatted_address);
                        else
                        $("#error").append("Unable to retrieve your address<br />");
                    });
                },
                function(positionError){
                    $("#error").append("Error: " + positionError.message + "<br />");
                },
                {
                    enableHighAccuracy: true,
                    timeout: 10 * 1000 // 10 seconds
                });
            });
            $("#calculate-route").submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                calculateRoute($("#from").val(), $("#to").val());
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 50%;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <form id="calculate-route" name="calculate-route" action="#" method="get">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="from"><font size="6"><b>Source :</font></label> 
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="from" name="from" required="required" placeholder="An address" size="25"/> 
                </td> 
                <td>
                    <label for="to"><font size="6"><b>Destination :</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="to" name="to" required="required" placeholder="Another address" size="25"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Route"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="reset"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <div id="map" border></div>
    <p id="error"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

In this code I have created a map where user enter source as well as destination through which we can get the route through map after submit on get route button but my problem is that before click on submit button map are not display after click on submit button it work perfectly. So, How can I fix this problem ?Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: you are not initialising the map on page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On page load you need to initialise the map if you wish to see it before attempting to get directions.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script async defer src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&callback=initMap"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var map;

        function initMap(){
            var options = {
                zoom: 10,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.08672, 79.42444),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById("map"), options );       
        }


        function calculateRoute(from, to) {


            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            var directionsRequest = {
                origin: from,
                destination: to,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
            };
            directionsService.route(
                directionsRequest,
                function(response, status)
                {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
                    {
                        new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                            map: map,
                            directions: response
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    $("#error").append("Unable to retrieve your route<br />");
                }
            );
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if (typeof navigator.geolocation == "undefined") {
                $("#error").text("Your browser doesn't support the Geolocation API");
                return;
            }
            $("#from-link, #to-link").click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var addressId = this.id.substring(0, this.id.indexOf("-"));

                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                    geocoder.geocode({
                        "location": new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
                    },
                    function(results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                        $("#" + addressId).val(results[0].formatted_address);
                        else
                        $("#error").append("Unable to retrieve your address<br />");
                    });
                },
                function(positionError){
                    $("#error").append("Error: " + positionError.message + "<br />");
                },
                {
                    enableHighAccuracy: true,
                    timeout: 10 * 1000 // 10 seconds
                });
            });
            $("#calculate-route").submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                calculateRoute($("#from").val(), $("#to").val());
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 50%;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <form id="calculate-route" name="calculate-route" action="#" method="get">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="from"><font size="6"><b>Source :</font></label> 
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="from" name="from" required="required" placeholder="An address" size="25"/> 
                </td> 
                <td>
                    <label for="to"><font size="6"><b>Destination :</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="to" name="to" required="required" placeholder="Another address" size="25"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Route"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="reset"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <p id="error"></p>
</body>
</html>
```